# How To Write Condition Statement based on Data from Database

Tags: database, vb.net

I am new learner for vb. I created 2 form (Form1 & Form2)

Form1 is a profile subject for user which will be saved in database. There is three combobox = Name,Subject 1, Subject 2.

**form1 Screen Shot:**

[image: Screen Shot]

View in database : I don't have any problem to save the data into database. I used the code below.

**Database Screen Shot:**

[image: Screen Shot]

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim constr As String = "server=localhost;user=root;database=test;port=3306;password=root123;SslMode=none"
    Dim conn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(constr)
    Dim result As Integer
    'If True Then
    Try
        conn.Open()
        With {}
            Dim cmd As MySqlCommand

            cmd = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO profilesubject(name,subject1,subject2) VALUES(@name,@subject1,@subject2)", conn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", ComboBox1.Text)

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subject1", ComboBox2.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subject2", ComboBox3.Text)
            result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            'conn.Close()
        End With
        'End If

        If result > 0 Then

            MsgBox("Record has been saved")

        Else
            MsgBox("Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString())
        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
```

For example :

User 1( Name : John, Subject 1:Mathematics, Subject 2: English)

User 2( Name : Mark, Subject 1:Mathematics, Subject 2: English)

User 3(Name : Brenda, Subject 1:History, Subject 2: Science)

After the data have been saved, when we click button in form1, form2 will appear.

**form2 Screen Shot:**

[image: Screen Shot]

form2 has 2 combobox which is subject and name. Based on the data saved from previous database, If the user choose 'Mathematics' for subject in form2, the name who choose 'Mathematics' will appear in the combobox for name(which select from database). So the combobox value should appear (John and Mark), If the user choose 'History' for subject, the combobox for name should appear 'Brenda'.

The problem is, i don't know how to write a proper condition statement from database. This is my code. but it is not working. I hope you guys can help me to solve it.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim connStr As String = "server=localhost;user=root;database=test;port=3306;password=root123;SslMode=none"
    Dim con As New MySqlConnection(connStr)
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand()

    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
    con.Open()
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText = "select subject1,subject2 FROM profilesubject WHERE subject1=@subject1,subject2=@subject2)"
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    cmd.Parameters("@subject1").Value = ComboBox1.Text
    cmd.Parameters("@subject2").Value = ComboBox1.Text

    If (reader.Item("@subject1").Equals(ComboBox1.Text) & (reader.Item("@subject2").Equals(ComboBox1.Text))) Then

        Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT `id`, `name`, `subject1`, `subject2` FROM test.profilesubject", con)
        Dim table As New DataTable()

        adapter.Fill(table)

        ComboBox1.DataSource = table

        ComboBox1.ValueMember = "id"
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "name"
    End If
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: The With...End With doesn't seem to be doing anything. Try deleting these lines.

Comment: You are executing your reader before you add the parameters.  You also need to read from the reader in order to access the information.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, Form1.Subject1, Form1.Subject2, and Form2.Subject combo boxes all have the same list of subjects. So, you want, on Form2 in combo Name a list of all students who have chosen the subject in Form2.Subject either as Subject1 or Subject2.

To accomplish this you need to search 2 columns for the subject. You need the id and name returned.

Select name, id From test.profilesubject Where subject1 = @subject Or subject2 = @subject;

A Using...End Using block will close and dispose your database objects that may be using unmanaged code. This will happen even if there is an error.

Good job using Parameters! This is very important to protect your database.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectionChangeCommitted
        'Use this event instead of SelectedIndexChanged so it won't jump
        'around when you load the combobox
        Dim connStr As String = "server=localhost;user=root;database=test;port=3306;password=root123;SslMode=none"
        Dim table As New DataTable()
        Try
            Using con As New MySqlConnection(connStr)
                'Pass the sql statement and the connection to
                'the Constructor of the Command
                Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("Select name, id From test.profilesubject Where subject1 = @subject Or subject2 = @subject;", con)
                    'you are looking for the same value in subject1 and subject2
                    'so you only need one parameter
                    'Check the data type of the subject field in your database
                    'and alter this line if necessary
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@subject", MySqlDbType.Text).Value = ComboBox1.Text
                    con.Open()
                    'the Load method of a DataTable takes a DataReader as
                    'a parameter and ExecuteReader returns a DataReader
                    table.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
        If table.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            ComboBox1.DataSource = table
            ComboBox1.ValueMember = "id"
            ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "name"
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Sorry, no matches")
        End If
End Sub
```